# Chat OneBox support for IDN (Internationalized Domain Name)?

Tags: feature-request, chat

Chat is great at recognizing URLs that are entered and automatically converting them to clickable links. Unfortunately this breaks with respect to IDNs.

Example:

> [http://例え.テスト/](http://%E4%BE%8B%E3%81%88.%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88/)

(It also isn't working here in post bodies either.)

Comment: hai, I agree. :)

Comment: I think the better way to word this would be **support [IRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier) instead of only [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) syntax**.